# Calculate relative rotation between a vector and its negative

Tags: linear-algebra

How do we find the rotation that rotates $v$ to -$v$, for arbitrary vector $v$.

The naive way of getting an axis using the cross product won't work here, because the cross product of $v, -v$ is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If your space has more than two dimensions, then there are infinitely many options, and they are all equally good. Just pick one.

To be more specific, you could pick any plane that contains $v$ and the origin, and rotate that $180^\circ$, keeping everything that's orthogonal to the plane fixed in place.

Comment: How do you "rotate through that"? Given $v$ and some arbitrary vector $q$, how does that allow us to define a rotation between the original $v$ and $-v$?

Comment: @user3180 I was thinking of rotation as a continuous motion. Then I realized that might not be what you meant. So I changed my answer.

Comment: I need concrete math formulas. I can't figure out what to do from your answer

Comment: @user3180 Pick any orthonormal basis where the first basis vector points in the direction of $v$. Then you can apply the transformation represented by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&-1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&1&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&0&1&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}$$Where the diagonal is all $1$ except the top two entries, and everything else is $0$.

Comment: ... In 3-dimensional space, it looks like this: $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$